# Randomizing Shapes with Polymorphism C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to work on an exercise I found in a C# book I'm currently going through. The exercise is based on inheritance and polymorphism and using the example of Shapes.
The concept is to insert a number into the GUI, that number is passed in and a random combination of three shapes are to appear on the screen.

Right now, I've gotten it to where I can get random shapes on each click, say if the number 5 is passed in, I get 5 instances of the same shape.

The goal is to try to get a random combination of the three different types of shapes so that if 5 is passed in, you may get 2 circles, 1 square, and 1 speckled circle.

I've tried stepping through the debugger and I'm having trouble understanding why my Shape method isn't being called at each iteration of my DrawShapes method and is only being called once per execution. I've posted the relevant code from my solution below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Canvas class

```
    public void DrawShapes(int numberOfShapes)
    {
        if (numberOfShapes < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        var randomVariable = new Random();

        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfShapes; i++)
        {
            var x = randomVariable.Next(0, this.canvas.Width - sizeOfLargestShape);
            var y = randomVariable.Next(0, this.canvas.Height - sizeOfLargestShape);

            this.newShape = new Shape(x, y);
            this.listOfShapes.Add(this.newShape);
        }
    }
```

Shape class

```
    private Shape()
    {
        this.randomShape = new RandomShape();
        this.newShapeType = this.randomShape.GetUniqueShape(this);
        this.randomNumber = new Random();
    }

    public Shape(Point location) : this()
    {
        this.point = location;
    }

    public Shape(int x, int y) : this()
    {
        this.point = new Point(x, y);
    }
```

RandomShape class

```
    public ShapeType GetUniqueShape(Shape myShape)
    {
        this.square = new SquareShape(myShape);
        this.circle = new CircleShape(myShape);
        this.speckledCircle = new SpeckledCircleShape(myShape);

        this.listOfAllShapeTypes = new List<ShapeType>
        {
           this.square,
           this.circle,
           this.speckledCircle
        };

        this.randomInt = this.myRandom.Next(0, 2);
        return this.listOfAllShapeTypes[this.randomInt];
    }
```

Comment: I don't know the output you're getting, but `GetUniqueShape` can't return a `speckledCircle` at all, since the `Next` method is upper-exclusive.

Comment: Oh. I thought next was going to be the index of the list so for three elements [0, 1, 2]. I'll switch it and try it.

Answer (score 1):

I would tend to do something like this:

```
Shape myShape = null;

switch (myRandom.Next(0, 3))
{
    case 0:
        myShape = new Square();
        break;
    case 1:
        myShape = new Circle();
        break;
    case 2:
        myShape = new SpeckledCircle();
        break;
}
```

Put that in a method and call it each time you need a random shape.